# Setting a primary key with ROW_NUMBER in a view mapped with Entity Fluent API makes linq timeout

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

My problem is the following : I map my view to an object through Entity Fluent API. I needed a view containing an few left joins, an there were no unique identifier in the tables, therefore Entity always returned the same set of object. In a few different threads / blogs, I saw a solution consisting of add a column with

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id))
```

I then tried to map it in Entity :
in my class I add a property

```
public long Row { get; set; }
```

and in my configuration class I add

```
HasKey(imc => imc.Row).HasColumnName("Row")
```

Apparently, the mapping works. What doesn't work is that, when I query the objects with linq, even a Count() will timeout ; however the request itself only returns about 200 lines when used in a SQL Management Studio environement.

Has anyone ever seen this issue ?

**EDIT:**
I have been able to bypass the problem by replacing the "row_number()" with a newid() in the MS SQL View, but I'm still afraid it might be a problem later on.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is slow which causes the timeout. About 1 million people have seen this before. You would need to analyze the query plan. Computing a row number over the whole table if unindexed can be slow. Also, a row number cannot be used as a key because it's values changes when you change the underlying data. EF does not support changing keys.

If you use `newid()` as the "key" in the view then you get fresh IDs each time. I think you might not be aware of the fact that a view is merely a shortcut for that particular query. It's contents are not stored anywhere.

Introduce a column that can be used as a key. For example an `IDENTITY` column.